# Swift semaphore not waiting for function to finish before calling UI

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, semaphore

I'm trying to delay a segue until I get a response from a `reverseGeocodeLocation` call. However, when using breakpoints to check when the value actually changes, it's still happening after the UI transition occurs. I've tried having the function be a void and with the current `String` return.

EDITED CODE:

```
func getReversedGeocodeLocation(completionHandler: (String, NSError?) ->()) {

    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { () -> Void in

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(self.newMeetupLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            else if placemarks?.count > 0 {

            }
            else {
                print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }

            completionHandler(placemarks!.first!.name! ?? "", error)
        })

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)

    }
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
}
```

OLD CODE:

```
let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1) //even with 0, it's not working

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { () -> Void in

            self.newAddress = self.getReversedGeocodeLocation()

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
        }

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

        //dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)

        print(self.newAddress + ".")

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainToNewAddress", sender: self)

func getReversedGeocodeLocation() -> String{

    var address = ""
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(self.newAddressLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        else if placemarks?.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks?.first!
            address = pm!.name!
        }
        else {
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })

    return address
}
```

Comment: (1) You should create the semaphore with count = 0. (2) May be your `getReversedGeocodeLocation()` is async itself?

Comment: Using a semaphore is needlessly complicated.  Simply pass a completion closure to `getReversedGeocodeLocation` and invoke that closure from the completion handler of `reverseGeocodeLocation`; have the closure perform the segue

Comment: Your semaphore in the above function is useless.. Why bother dispatching async if you're going to use the semaphore to "wait". You could use the semaphore on: `reverseGeocodeLocation` instead to make it synchronous.

Comment: Yeah I realized it made no sense once you got me looking back at why I was using it in the first place. I edited my code, it's still not working, but I hope it's in the right direction

Comment: @brandon not sure if this is a possible problem, but when I have breakpoints for my `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation` and for `dispatch_semaphore_wait` the former is in thread 10 and the later is in thread 1

Comment: I'd just use a completion handler and dispatch it on the main queue to push your segue: http://ideone.com/vWAfu7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a semaphore and dispatching the call to `getReversedGeocodeLocation` is unnecessarily complicated.  `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation` is already asynchronous.  If you simply pass a completion handler closure to `getReversedGeocodeLocation` then you can use that to invoke the segue;

```
self.getReversedGeocodeLocation(self.newAddressLocation, completionHandler: { (address,error) in 
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    guard let address = address else {
        print("No address returned")
        return
    }

    self.newAddress = address
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainToNewAddress", sender: self)
    })
})

func getReversedGeocodeLocation(addressLocation: String, completionHandler:((address: String?, error: NSError?) -> Void))) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(self.newAddressLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

        var address = nil

        if placeMarks.count > 0 {
            if let pm = placeMarks!.first {
                address  = pm.name
            }
        } else {
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }

        completionHandler(address,error)
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm getting "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type" for `guard let address = address else` EDIT: nevermind, found it in the completionHandler

Comment: first of all thank you, it works. However, I would at least like to know why my code wasn't working. Did I need to simply put the `self.performSegueWithIdentifier` within the `dispatch_async` and still have the semaphore framework? Or should I always look to do this if I can?

Comment: Avoiding semaphores is best.  The completion handler approach is extremely common in the iOS world

Comment: But to answer you question, the ` dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)` needs to go where you are calling the completion handler.  The problem wit this approach is, however, that the `dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)` will block the main thread and make the UI non-responsive

Comment: Okay thanks, when working on the app I'm trying to learn the best "iOS world" practices so I can feel better about the quality of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its a problem with the semaphore, its with your `getReversedGeocodeLocation` function. the `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation` is an async function, therefore the return statement is going to execute before the completion block of `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation` is executed, which is why `self.newAddress` is being assigned an empty string.

To fix this you could use another semaphore inside the `getReversedGeocodeLocation` to block until the completion handler is finished, or use a delegate to notify something that the completion handler is finished (which is usually the right way to do it).

Comment: should my semaphore be within the async block or around it?

Comment: Put the entire dispatch_async block in the reverseGeocodeLocation and it didn't produce different changes.

Comment: You need the semaphore signal to be done INSIDE the CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation completion block.

Comment: put a new `dispatch_semaphore_create` at the start of `getReversedGeocodeLocation`, put a signal at the end of `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation` and put a wait just before the return statement, and that should be all you need

Comment: `completionHandler(placemarks!.first!.name! ?? "", error)
                
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)`

I put the signal afterwards and now it's running forever